# Node Require with two Parenthesis

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently im try to read codes of [koajs](http://koajs.com) and find this line of code:

```
var debug = require('debug')('koa-route');
```

What this mean ? why use ('debug') and then ('koa-route') ? you can find the code [here](https://github.com/koajs/route/blob/master/index.js) . and i say that i find this line of code in koa-route middle ware defination

Comment: `require('debug')` returns a function.

Comment: so require return a function and ('koa-route') is parameter?

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/visionmedia/debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module basically looks something like this:

```
function toRun() {
  // do stuff
}

module.exports = toRun;
```

Then your script code does the following:

```
var ran = require('torun')();
```

This is a convenient way to expose something most often used, but also usable if you want to expose some methods directly on the exported `Function`. For example:

```
function toRun() {
  // do stuff
}

toRun.moreStuff = function() {
  // and again
};

module.exports = toRun;
```

Then to get access to the additional functions you can just grab the entire thing:

```
var toRun = require('torun');
var ran = toRun();
var stuff = toRun.moreStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to comment and [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug) defination require('debug') return a function and ('koa-route') is parameter of this function.

Comment: More info on [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)